# Monogame 3.3 SoundEffect play Freezes

Tags: android, monogame, xamarin

After using Monogame 3.3 with Xamarin Android, SoundEffect.Play method freezes the game. I try to convert wav files 8bit mono, 16bit mono no changes. This error on Samsung T101 android 4.0.3 but SoundEffects works with another android device which has 4.2.2.

I don't have this problem with Monogame 3.2. Any suggestion?

Thank you!

Android debug log below.

```
The thread 'Unknown' (0x4) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
Failed to generate OpenAL data buffer: 
04-22 23:34:04.380 I/mono-stdout(10068): Failed to generate OpenAL data buffer: 

Failed to get buffer bits: , format=Stereo16, size=73632, sampleRate=44100
04-22 23:34:04.380 I/mono-stdout(10068): Failed to get buffer bits: , format=Stereo16, size=73632, sampleRate=44100
04-22 23:34:04.390 D/Mono    (10068): DllImport searching in: 'openal32.dll' ('./libopenal32.so').
04-22 23:34:04.390 D/Mono    (10068): Searching for 'alDistanceModel'.
04-22 23:34:04.990 D/Mono    (10068): Image addref System.Runtime.Serialization[0x28084d0] -> System.Runtime.Serialization.dll[0x27ef090]: 1
04-22 23:34:04.990 D/Mono    (10068): Assembly System.Runtime.Serialization[0x28084d0] added to domain RootDomain, ref_count=1
04-22 23:34:04.990 D/Mono    (10068): AOT module 'System.Runtime.Serialization.dll.so' not found: Cannot load library: load_library[1091]: Library '/data/data/com.homemadegames.exterminator/lib/System.Runtime.Serialization.dll.so' not found
04-22 23:34:04.990 D/Mono    (10068): Assembly Ref addref MonoGame.Framework[0x1c80558] -> System.Runtime.Serialization[0x28084d0]: 2
04-22 23:34:04.990 D/Mono    (10068): Assembly Ref addref System.Runtime.Serialization[0x28084d0] -> mscorlib[0x1c66118]: 9
04-22 23:35:31.110 D/dalvikvm(10068): GC_CONCURRENT freed 159K, 5% free 8403K/8775K, paused 5ms+1ms
04-22 23:38:12.350 D/dalvikvm(10068): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 2% free 8905K/9031K, paused 5ms+1ms
```

Comment: That error could mean that your application is running out of memory.

Comment: Have you tried making a project with only this sound effect playing and see if it makes no difference ? Also, http://community.monogame.net and https://github.com/mono/MonoGame/issues/ has solved me a lot of problems like the one you have, because actual developers answers questions.

Comment: Could you also add the code you use to play the sound ?

Comment: Content.Load<SoundEffect>("Sounds/click").Play();